# How to set a position to an AnchorPane (not declared)?

Tags: javafx

I spent a long time searching for how to add a position to an `AnchorPane` (not declared means like that: `setMethode(new AnchorPane());`).
Adding `Layout (x,y)`, Setting `Pref(Width and Height)` etc.

I tried that but it didn't work:

```
           .someMethode(new AnchorPane(
                   .setLayoutX(12);
                   .setLayoutY(222);
                   .setPrefWidth(1026);
           ));
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're probably refering to is the *double brace initialization* (see [What is Double Brace initialization in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1958636/2991525)). You'd need to write it like this:

```
.someMethode(new AnchorPane() {{
               setLayoutX(12);
               setLayoutY(222);
               setPrefWidth(1026);
       }});
```

However I consider this a bad practice, since you create a new anonymus class by using the double brace initialisation.

#### Alternatives:

- Use a variable

  ```
  AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
  pane.setLayoutX(12);
  pane.setLayoutY(222);
  pane.setPrefWidth(1026);
  ...
  <some expression>.someMethode(pane);
  ```
- create a method doing this:

  ```
  static AnchorPane createAnchorPane(double layoutX, double layoutY, double prefWidth) {
      AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
      pane.setLayoutX(layoutX);
      pane.setLayoutY(layoutY);
      pane.setPrefWidth(prefWidth);
      return pane;
  }
  ....
  <some expression>.someMethode(createAnchorPane(12, 22, 1026));
  ```
- Create a builder for `AnchorPane`s
- Use fxml and [`FXMLLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html), which allows you to create a node structure from a file. It may be easier to create a bigger node structure that way. This would be a fxml file for your `AnchorPane`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane prefWidth="1026" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" layoutX="12" layoutY="222" >
    <!-- add something else here??? -->
</AnchorPane>
```